# Matplotlib in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a code to plot a graph which should dynamically change with change in data. The code is -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
matplotlib.rcParams['backend.qt4']='PySide'
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class MatplotlibWidget(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self):
        '''super(MatplotlibWidget, self).__init__(Figure())'''
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, Figure())

    def setup(self, a, b):
        self.x = []
        self.y = []
        self.i = 0
        self.j = 0  
        self.count = 70
        self.lb = 0

        self.lowlim = a
        self.uplim = b

        self.figure = Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.readFile = open('test.txt','r')
        self.sepFile = self.readFile.read().split('\n')
        self.readFile.close()
        self.sepFile.pop()


        for self.plots in self.sepFile:
            self.y.append(int(self.plots)) 

        self.big_x = np.arange(0,21,0.1)

        self.x = self.big_x[self.lowlim:self.uplim] 
        self.ply = self.y[self.lowlim:self.uplim]

        while self.lb < self.count:
            self.ub = self.lb
            if (self.ply[self.lb] < 20):
                self.ub = self.ub + 1
                if (self.ub < self.count):
                    if(self.ply[self.ub] < 20):
                            self.axes.axvspan(self.x[self.lb],self.x[self.ub], color = 'red', alpha = 0.5)
                    else:
                        self.axes.axvspan(self.x[self.lb],self.x[self.lb], color = 'red', alpha = 0.5)              
            self.lb = self.lb + 1


        self.axes.plot(self.x,self.ply)
        self.draw()


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.lb = 0
        self.count = 70
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.widget = MatplotlibWidget()
        self.widget.setup(0, 70)
        pause(5)
        self.change()
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")     

        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton() 
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "clickme", None,             QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.change)

        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addSpacing(50)      
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.layout.addSpacing(25)      
        self.layout.addWidget(self.widget)

        MainWindow.setLayout(self.layout)                

    def change(self):
        self.widget.axes.cla()
        self.widget.setup(self.widget.lowlim+70, self.widget.uplim+70)
        self.widget.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    MainWindow = QtGui.QWidget()

    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)

    MainWindow.show()

    app.exec_()
```

The **     **`enter code here` portion shows the usage of the 'pause' function. However, the program only pauses, goes 7 frames ahead and then prints from 7-14. Ideally, it should print from 0-7, then pause for 5 seconds and then print 7-14. Can someone explain how exactly to do that using pause?

Answer (score 0):

To have dynamic changes in matplotlib, try using the "animate" function:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/double_pendulum_animated.html